# Delete old maven artifact versions from Nexus Repository

Tags: maven, nexus

we have a maven project for our database entities. For each release we have several sub-releases.

The version 7.6.3 will be split into several sub-versions like

7.6.3a

7.6.3b

...

Because each sub-version can have several changes before releasing this sub-release out artifact version number looks like

7.6.3a-1021

7.6.3a-1022

7.6.3a-1023

7.6.3b-1024

7.6.3b-1025

...

The sequential number comes from teamcity (our CI system).

Now I want to delete all not final sub-versions. In my example above:

**7.6.3a-1021**

**7.6.3a-1022**

7.6.3a-1023

**7.6.3b-1024**

7.6.3b-1025

TeamCity calls a linux script with a bunch of stuff in it. I could also extend this script in order to delete several artifacts from nexus.

I looked into the REST-API and I can delete a single JAR file from one version with this command:

```
curl -v --request DELETE --user "USER:PW" --silent http://SERVER:8081/repository/companyrelease/dev/developer1/maven/dummy/7.6.3-1340/dummy-7.6.3-1340.jar
```

But then only this single jar is gone. What I want is to delete the whole version. Also I am wondering if I need to do something on order to correct to metadata?

Thanks for your help
Hauke

Comment: Have you taken a look into the REST API docs of Nexus?